# some icons and text missing from VS2013 winforms project upgraded from VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, telerik, visual-studio-2013

I have a winforms project I built using VS2010 using Telerik Controls 2009 Q4. I have moved the system to Visual Studio 2013 and some of the icons disappear at funny times (when it loses focus the icon seems to disappear - picture 1) and the text and the little triangle indication dropdownlist in the radComboBox is not visible - even though it is there (I can drop select from the list even though I can not see the text - picture 2). Other controls such as grid seems to be working just fine. All functionality is there only I can't see the text and some icons...any ideas?

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

EDIT: should mention I am using a virtual machine running Windows 7 Ultimate 64. The host is Windows 8.1. I installed the original package 2010 on both the VM and the host and the controls render just fine. It is when using VS2013 that this happens

Answer (score 0):

I looked at themes thinking this might have something to do with it but go nowhere.

I ended up reinstalling VS2010 on my dev machine and now it works fine. This is not ideal but it works.